# Two page form ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

everyone.
I need to create a model with a little more data, using two pages:

- one with metadata
- another one with a long list of data (of the same tipe)

---

So, my spec is:

- first page has metadata ( many labels, not just one)
- long data (a long list of items of the same time) should be on the second page
- the first page redirect to the second page through a button
- when submiting the form on the second page, the website should return to the first page. Data will be available

---

What I have done since now:

- I have the first page, and the metadata loads correctly
- I have the UI for the second page
- I have the link to the second page

What I can do:

- Save the data from the second page in the repo/db in order to use it on the first page

What i can't do (yet):

- ***** Preserve the first page state when returning to it *****

---

How should I accomplish the required behaviour ? (the marked item)

PS:If you think it's too much redundant description, comment and i'll delete some of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you have to persist it somehow. In HTTP, requests are idempotent: each one is unique and unaffected by anything that's occurred before or since in the client-server communication. When you do your first submit, unless you persist what was submitted, then it just goes into the ether with your next request.

*How* you persist it is entirely up to you. You could actually use a database table and then look up the record from there when you need it. You could use some sort of NoSQL solution like Redis, or you could simply use `TempData`.

Bear in mind, with some of these approaches (Redis/`TempData`), you will likely need to serialize/deserialize the data, first, usually to/from JSON. Assuming you have a database table with appropriate columns to house each piece of data, you'd obviously be fine without serialization there.

Answer (score 0):

TempData can be used to store data between two consecutive requests. TempData values will be retained during redirection.

A scenario that fits the usage of TempData, is when data needs to persist between two requests – a redirect scenario.

Example/Useful Link:

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc

http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/what-is-aspnet-mvc-tempdata.html